# Unable to override base class method in derived class

Tags: ruby

Here are the Ruby classes I have:

```
class MyBase
  class << self
     def static_method1
        @@method1_var ||= "I'm a  base static method1"
     end

     def static_method1=(value)
        @@method1_var = value
     end

     def static_method2
        @@method2_var ||= "I'm a base static method2"
     end

     def static_method2=(value)
        @@method2_var = value
     end
  end

  def method3
    MyBase::static_method1
  end
end

class MyChild1 < MyBase
end

class MyChild2 < MyBase
  class << self
     def static_method1
        @@method1_var ||= "I'm a child static method1"
     end
  end
end

c1 = MyChild1.new
puts c1.method3 #"I'm a  base static method1" - correct


c2 = MyChild2.new
puts c2.method3  # "I'm a  base static method1" - incorrect. I want to get "I'm a child static method1"
```

I'm aware of `attr_accessor` and modules, but I can't use use them here because I want them to give default values in `MyBase class`. I want to override `MyBase.static_method1` in `MyChild2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that method3 is always explicitly calling the method on the base class. Change it to this:

```
def method3
  self.class.static_method1
end
```

After that, consider not using `@@`.

`@@` in ruby is extremely counterintuitive and rarely means what you think it means.

The problem with `@@` is that it is shared across the *all* of the inherited classes and the base class. [See this blog post for an explanation](http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2006/11/18/class-and-instance-variables-in-ruby/).

Comment: <<The problem with @@ is that it is shared across the all of the inherited classes and the base class>> How do I use default values then?

Comment: @Alexandre You can still use instance variables in class methods, where they are called *class instance variables*.

Comment: @Alexandre use class instance variables (`@variable` in a class method) Those are safe, as Andrew points out.